# nasm displaying a dword with printf

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

this is my code (test.asm)

expected "num = 1337"

output: "num = 4199373"

question: How do I fix it.

intent: curiosity towards assembly language, not assignment.

```
; nasm -fwin32 test.asm
; gcc test.obj -o test
    extern _printf
    global _main

    section .text
_main:
    push num
    push msg
    call _printf
    add esp, 8
    ret

msg db 'num = %i', 0xa, 0
num dd 1337
```

changing `push num`  to `push dword [num]` fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push num` pushes the address of `num` (similar to `push msg`), but not the value contained there.

You need `push dword [num]` instead.

Comment: NASM's COFF is not Microsoft's PE-COFF. NASM's COFF is the same as COFF supported by DJGPP gcc.