# System Write Integer

Tags: assembly, formatting, x86, memory-address, sys

I'm currently working on a small ASM program that grabs the process ID and then writes it out the screen.

Here is the code:

```
SECTION .bss

    Pid: resb 4

SECTION .text

global start

start:
    mov eax, 0x14       ; System call 20 - Get PID
    push eax            ; Push to stack for BSD
    int 0x80            ; Call
    mov edx, eax        ; Save return value in EDX
    add esp, 0x4        ; Clean up the stack

    push 0x4            ; Push lenth of 4 bytes
    mov [Pid], edx      ; Move address to Pid Buffer
    push Pid
    push 0x1            ; Set file descriptor as 1 (stdout)
    mov eax, 0x4        ; Set system call 4 - Write
    push eax            ; Push the system call to stack
    int 0x80            ; Call
    add esp, 0x10       ; Clean up the stack

    mov eax, 1          ; Set call 1 - sys_exit
    mov ebx, 0          ; All went well
    int 0x80            ; Call
```

My issue is that the program is printing the PID as a string and not an integer, too explain here is the same address displayed in GDB with different output formats.

```
String:  0x2016 <Pid>:  "z\035"
Hex:     0x2016 <Pid>:  0x00001d7a
Integer: 0x2016 <Pid>:  7546
```

The system write call is printing the string, and I need it to print the integer.

Is there some trick to do this, or am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Comment: Which number system (binary, decimal, hexadecimal) you want to use?

Comment: I would like it to return a unsigned integer.

Comment: A return value to operating system? Then it's not about printing at all. In that case `mov eax, 1`, `mov ebx, my_value`, `int 0x80`. Or do you mean printing an unsigned integer in decimal?

Comment: Sorry, I worded that badly. Yes I mean to print the integer, I'm trying converting it to a string first now.

Comment: A version of this without libc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the , in which case it comes down to: how to call libc from assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out the problem. Here is the solution for anyone that needs this in the future.

As a quick recap, the problem was taking the integer returned from the system call GET_PID and converting it to a string for use with SYS_WRITE.

The first step was to take the integer and isolate each digit; for example:

```
Returned PID: 60015 - Grab each integer own its own i.e. 5 1 0 0 6
```

To achieve this I used the DIV function to divide the integer by 10, this leaves the remainder in EDX. If we look at the math 60015/10 would result in 6001.5, so the remainder 5 would be stored in EDX. A loop can then be used to retrieve each integer until it reaches zero, followed by a JZ to exit the loop.

The next step is to take each integer and find its ASCII code to store into a buffer. To do this, a translation table is used:

```
LookUpDig db "0123456789"
```

Take the digit stored in EDX and use it as an index into the translation table, this will retrieve the ASCII version of that integer for use with sys_write.

```
mov cl, [LookUpDig+edx]
```

Take the ASCII value and insert it into the buffer for the result.

```
mov [ebp], cl
```

Place this into the loop to build the string from the integer returned.

The full program should give more context to the solution, I hope the comments are detailed enough to explain each line of code.

```
;*************************************************************
; Date    : 02/04/2013                                       *
; Compile : nasm -f macho -o pid.o space.asm                 *
; Link    : ld -macosx_version_min 10.7 -o pid pid.o         *          
; Descr.  : Prints the process PID, could be used in a       *
;           larger program.                                  *
; Nasm v. : NASM version 0.98.40                             *
;*************************************************************

SECTION .data

    LookUpDig db "0123456789"         ; Translation Table
    PIDString db "PID: "
    PIDLength equ $-PIDString

SECTION .bss

    PID: resb 8                       ; Reserve space for result

SECTION .text

global start

start:
    mov eax, 0x14             ; GET_PID call
int 0x80                  ; Call  
mov ebx, 0xA              ; Set divider to 10
mov ebp, PID+6            ; Save the address of PID+6 to EBP
jnz LoopMe                ; Run the loop to convert int to string

LoopMe: 
div ebx                   ; Divide the PID by 10
mov cl, [LookUpDig+edx]   ; Copy ASCII value to CL
mov [ebp], cl             ; Copy CL to PID buffer
dec ebp                   ; Move to next byte in the buffer
xor edx, edx              ; Clear the remainder, leave in for some weird results :)
inc eax                   ; Increase EAX tricking JNZ
dec eax                   ; Decrease to get back to original value
jnz LoopMe                ; Keep looping until EAX is zero (all integers converted)
jz PrintOut               ; When done call the print out function

PrintOut:
push PIDLength            ; Push PIDString Length
push PIDString            ; Push PIDString
push 0x1                  ; FD stdout
mov eax, 0x4              ; sys_write call
push eax                  ; Push call (BSD)
int 0x80                  ; Call
add esp, 0x10             ; Clear up the stack

mov [PID+7], byte 0xA     ; Push a newline to PID string

push 0x8                  ; Max length of 8 bytes
push PID                  ; Push PID value
push 0x1                  ; FD stdout
mov eax, 0x4              ; sys_write call
push eax                  ; Push call (BSD)
int 0x80                  ; Call
add esp, 0x10             ; Clean up stack

mov eax, 0x1              ; Set system_call
push 0x0                  ; Exit_code 0
int 0x80                  ; Call
```

I hope this helps anyone else out in the future who has the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can either convert your integer to string and then print the string (with `mov eax,4` ... `int 0x80`, as you do now), or, you can use `printf` with `call printf`, which needs `global main` (instead of `global start`), `extern printf`, and doing the linking with `gcc`.

An example on how to convert an integer into a decimal number (a string):
[How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/13166463#13166463)

An example on how to use `printf` in x86 assembly:
[nasm displaying a dword with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257224/nasm-displaying-a-dword-with-printf)

Note that you need **either** `extern printf` **or** `extern _printf`, and **either** `global main` **or** `global _main`, depending on your setup.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll try and convert the integer to a string first. Thanks, let's see how this goes :)

Comment: I can't seem to get any further, I've tried converting to a string but I can't access the decimal to do that. Also I would like to avoid calling C functions, I'm trying to stay pure to assembly.

Answer (score 1):

**Linux Version**

Here is a version of James Parker's code converted to run on **x86/x86_64 Linux**.

```
SECTION .data

    LookUpDig db "0123456789"             ; Translation Table
    PIDString db "PID: "
    PIDLength equ $-PIDString

SECTION .bss

    PID: resb 8                           ; Reserve space for result

SECTION .text

            global _start

    _start:
            mov     eax, 0x14             ; GET_PID call
            int     0x80                  ; Call
            mov     ebx, 0xA              ; Set divider to 10
            mov     ebp, PID+6            ; Save the address of PID+6 to EBP
            jnz     LoopMe                ; Run the loop to convert int to string

    LoopMe:
            div     ebx                   ; Divide the PID by 10
            mov     cl, [LookUpDig+edx]   ; Copy ASCII value to CL
            mov     [ebp], cl             ; Copy CL to PID buffer
            dec     ebp                   ; Move to next byte in the buffer
            xor     edx, edx              ; Clear the remainder, else weird results :)
            inc     eax                   ; Increase EAX tricking JNZ
            dec     eax                   ; Decrease to get back to original value
            jnz     LoopMe                ; Loop until EAX is zero (all integers converted)
            jz      PrintOut              ; When done call the print out function

    PrintOut:
            mov     edx, PIDLength        ; Push PIDString Length
            mov     ecx, PIDString        ; Push PIDString
            mov     ebx, 0x1              ; FD stdout
            mov     eax, 0x4              ; sys_write call
            int     0x80                  ; Call kernel

            mov     [PID+7], byte 0xA     ; Push a newline to PID string

            mov     edx, 0x8              ; Max length of 8 bytes
            mov     ecx, PID              ; Push PID value
            mov     ebx, 0x1              ; FD stdout
            mov     eax, 0x4              ; sys_write call
            int     0x80                  ; Call kernel

            mov     eax, 0x1              ; Set system_call
            xor     ebx,ebx               ; Exit_code 0
            int     0x80                  ; Call kernel
```

**build:**

```
nasm -f elf -o prnpid_32.o prnpid_32.asm
ld -o prnpid_32 prnpid_32.o                 # On native 32-bit machine
ld -m elf_i386 -o prnpid_32 prnpid_32.o     # On x86_64
```

**output:**

```
$ prnpid_32
PID: 1387
```